# Alternative method to display specific JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am extracting data from a JSON file using a URL like this:

```
$html5=file_get_contents("url");

$data = json_decode($html5);    

echo $data->a->k->f;
```

This displays `$27.58` which is correct.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{  
"a":{  
   "k":{  
     "c":"tr",
     "f":"$27.58",
     "fb":"$30.35",
     "ci":"12873809",
     "cname":"Cdkeysgame_com",
     "ep":"26.05",
     "epb":"28.66",
     "a":"5473091",
     "it":"steam",
     "sl":"0",
     "l":null,
     "lt":null,
     "x":0,
     "v":"retail",
     "ne":0,
     "so":0,
     "tr":304,
     "r":97,
     "cf":1,
     "p":"27.58317275",
     "pb":"30.3467843",
     "eci":"865723abbf1cbb952ad4d2da8a8c925e"
  },
  "k_1":{  
     "c":"gb",
     "f":"$27.64",
     "fb":"$30.40",
     "ci":"1065801",
     "cname":"World_of_games",
     "ep":"26.10",
     "epb":"28.71",
     "a":"781851",
     "it":"steam",
     "sl":"0",
     "l":null,
     "lt":null,
     "x":0,
     "v":"all",
     "ne":0,
     "so":0,
     "tr":1041328,
     "r":99,
     "cf":1,
     "p":"27.6361155",
     "pb":"30.39972705",
     "eci":"d01a7cacb0e424123985bfe2e53a0523"
  },
  "k_2":{  
     "c":"ch",
     "f":"$27.68",
     "fb":"$30.44",
     "ci":"696012",
     "cname":"G_hard",
     "ep":"26.14",
     "epb":"28.75",
     "a":"1287052",
     "it":"steam",
     "sl":"0",
     "l":null,
     "lt":null,
     "x":0,
     "v":"retail",
     "ne":0,
     "so":0,
     "tr":10818,
     "r":99,
     "cf":1,
     "p":"27.6784697",
     "pb":"30.44208125",
     "eci":"a6666c0a47acb70d14b757cd52f1b9cc"
  }}
```

I need to display the same data without using `k`. For example I want to:

```
 echo $data->a->'Something that specifies first element of 'a' i.e k and not'k_1' and 'k_2'->f;
```

Since I am scraping this content I cannot change anything like structure or data in this JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first entry under `a`, then you can decode as an array:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then get the first element of `$data['a']` and use that.  `current()` will also work:

```
echo reset($data['a'])['f'];
```

Or re-index `$data['a']` numerically and access the first one `0`:

```
echo array_values($data['a'])[0]['f'];
```

To catch them all:

```
foreach($data['a'] as $values) {
    echo $values['f'];
    //break; if you only want the first one
}
```

Comment: I used this code echo array_values($data['a'])[0]['f']; and I got this error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Because you didn't read the first sentence and first line of code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this so:

```
$object = json_decode($html5);

foreach ($object->a as $element) {
   echo $element->f;
}
```